# Output Serial Number and MAC address on CSV file using powershell with 2 columns

Tags: powershell, multiple-columns

I want to save the serial number and the MAC address of each machine to a CSV file. I will use a USB drive to run the powershell file on each computers and save it on a CSV file. I use the script below:

$MAC = Get-NetAdapter -Name "Ethernet"

$serial = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Bios).SerialNumber

$dir = Set-Content "$location" -Value "Serial Number,MAC Address"

$dir

$location = "C:\Users\Frangon\Desktop\$env:COMPUTERNAME.csv"

Add-Content $location $serial

Add-Content $location $MAC.MacAddress

The result is this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFstN.png)

I want the MAC address to be on the MAC address column and vice versa.

[This is the result of my noob script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFstN.png)

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777) and make sure that the screen shots show directly in the post, not just as links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are talking about is creating a `PSobject`. Also `Export-Csv`

```
New-object psobject -Property @{
    "Serial Number" = $(Get-WmiObject Win32_Bios).SerialNumber
    "Mac Address" = $(Get-NetAdapter -Name "Ethernet").MacAddress
} | Export-Csv -Path C:\ComputerDetials.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Comment: This works! Thank you so much Arc! Is there a way to contact you? You are so knowledgeable!

Comment: Well stackoverflow does have chat. [https://chat.stackoverflow.com](https://chat.stackoverflow.com)